# get current post title from inside another query loop

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, custom-post-type, posts

I have a single-page.php with a standard while loop. Inside that loop I have another loop that I want to output the post title that I am on/viewing, however because I have the get_the_title() within the inner loop of function futureEvent, its outputting that post's title instead:

```
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post(); ?>
...
 $futureEvents = get_posts($args);
  foreach ($futureEvents as $post) {
   $futureEvents = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($futureEvents->have_posts()) {
      echo '<div class="related-content"><h3>Upcoming ' . get_the_title() . ' Events</h3></div>';
   ?>
    <article class="post-item">
     <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </article>
    }
   }
}
```

In wordpress, I have a CPT with three posts added.
I have used get_the_title(118), however that hard-codes a post's id, but I want to get the title for any post from my CPT.

I have tried using get_the_title($post->$ID) and get_the_title($post_id), but that still outputs the incorrect post title.

Can anyone see how I can get the post title for the one I am on/viewing from inside that loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can get the post title for the one I am on/viewing from inside
> that loop?

You can use:

- [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) to get the full *post object* (a `WP_Post` instance) of the current post you're on/viewing.
- [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) to get just the *ID* of the post you're on/viewing.

So for example in your *inner* loop, you could display the above post's title like so:

```php
echo '<div class="related-content"><h3>Upcoming ' . get_the_title( get_queried_object() ) . ' Events</h3></div>';
```